# Opening Tkinter gui in the center or bottom or left or right the monitor screen

Tags: tkinter

I want a code whose function is that when a gui of tkinter window is opened, I can use that code and change the input of a widget to open that window at the top or left or right or even at the bottom and center of the monitor screen.

I couldn't think of a code myself. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You can use `.geometry()` on window to move the window, for example `win.geometry("+100+100")` will  move `win` to position (100, 100) on the screen.

Comment: To find the screen size use: `.winfo_screenwidth()` and `.winfo_screenheight()`. To find a window's size, use `.winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()`. Using that and what @ acw1668 suggested, you should be able to make your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "window_name".geometry("+100+100").

The digits inside the parenthesesis where on the screen the window will open.
Here is a good article on .geometry: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-geometry-method-in-tkinter/

Note: Remember that all monitors are different. So if you want to place it on the same place on all monitors you will have to figure out the size of the monitor first and then calculate the area of that monitor you want the widget to be placed.